# Pressing enter on a text input in javascript/HTML (bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried a lot of the solutions posted here related to forms (e.g. Prevent default, changing the form attribute) but I can't seem to get this to work. Basically, I've started with two bootstrap templates and so far it's going nicely. I now have a text box, and I want there to be another text box that is added when you "submit" (i.e. Press enter) in the first textbox. At the moment, the first text input is added by:

```
$('#item').after(
                    '<div class="form-group" onsubmit="return false"> <form class="form-horizontal" onSubmit="return false;"> </div><label for="exampleInputEmail1"> What was the value of the sale?</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputSaleValue" placeholder="Enter value"><form onsubmit="return false"> <form action="javascript:void(-1)"> <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Excluding</small></div>'
```

But at the moment the page just refreshes and takes me to the first part of this form I trying to generate.

Comment: please share your html and js file & try to create a working demo

Comment: Do you need one textbox??or whenever a user input enter key a new textbox will added??If it is one textbox then you can do it using jquery hide and show function or if you need multiple text box you can add it by append method, just let me know your need.

Answer (score 0):

I have this kind of template. I posted it here cause maybe you can use it as a stepping stone. Just run the code snippet:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<table>
  <tr>

    <td><button type="button" id="button1" style="margin: 10px;">Add Textbox</button>
  </tr>
</table>

</html>
<script>
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    addRow(this);
  });

  function addRow(btn) {
    var parentRow = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
    var table = parentRow.parentNode;
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "text";
    element1.name = "text1";
    element1.className = "text1"
    cell1.appendChild(element1);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with an example solution https://jsfiddle.net/37h6c1rs/

```js
$('#item').append('<div class="form-group" onsubmit="return false"> <form class="form-horizontal" onSubmit="return false;"> </div><label for="exampleInputEmail1"> What was the value of the sale?</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputSaleValue" placeholder="Enter value"><form onsubmit="return false"> <form action="javascript:void(-1)"> <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Excluding</small></div>');
        
$('#InputSaleValue').keypress(function(e){
  if (e.which === 13) {
    $('#item').append('<div><input type="text id="addedTextbox /></div>')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item"></div>
```

This might not be the exact solution that you are looking for, but this will help you to reach the destination.